# Is it safe to drive with spare wheel but with proper tire?

Tags: tires, wheels, lug-nut, spare-tire

I recently got a puncture and had to swap out the entire wheel. Luckily, the spare I had was a full size tyre, i.e.: not a skinny tyre like you sometimes see.

It looks roughly like this:

[image]

So, the *wheel* looks roughly like the one in the image but the rubber tyre itself is a full-size one that matches the rest of my tyres.

I used the same lug-nuts as before to attach the wheel. I do not know whether they are officially supported, however I didn't have any issues during the installation.

Someone warned my that this wheel is not as thick as standard alloyed wheels and there is a risk of it wearing out near the lug-nuts.

Is it a problem to drive like this, especially at long distances and high speeds?

Answer (score 1):

I have a set of alloys and a set of steel wheels looking very similar to that shown.

They do require their own nuts ie the alloys have one type of nut and the steels another.

The steels are perfectly fine especially as they are used in winter (well, were as I have now got a second set of alloys..) so you should be good to go.

Comment: I used the same nuts; didn't have any issues mounting it with them so I assume it's ok?

Comment: If the nuts are designed to work with both types of wheel then fine, if they aren’t then that could be a fatal assumption.

Comment: My RAV4 nuts work with alloys and spare tire steel wheel. However, the contact surface of nut with spare tire steel wheel is very small and the integrated washer doesn't make contact with the spare tire steel wheel. I wouldn't drive on the spare wheel for long durations given the marginal nut contact surface.

Comment: Hmm, that was my worry. I have no clue whether they are "officially" compatible or not. Will take a look at what the manual says.

Comment: Please do! My manual says they are compatible, but it also says the temporary spare is only for temporary use. I'd say the second of these two statements is enough for me not to even consider driving on spare wheel with tire replaced by one that can be used continuously...

Comment: It is a reasonable assumption that if the car manufacturer **supplied the spare wheel with the car** then it would use the same lug-nuts as the **stock wheels that came on the car**. Otherwise they would have to supply the appropriate lug-nuts, how else would you be expected to change your flat out to your spare while out on a drive far away from any garage or auto parts store.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I did not get my car new, but the second set of lug nuts are in a bag with the car manufacturers logo leading me to think they supplied the second set of nuts to go with the steel winter wheels... but it is my car - what they do or don’t do for you car is for you.

Comment: I think the concern is about galvanic corrosion. If you've got steel and aluminum in close contact for an extended period of time, bad things can happen. If the wheel and lug nuts are the same material, or coated with something to prevent this, it wouldn't be a problem.